# Are there any docs which states how to get a block from cosmos-SDK blockchains?

Tags: cosmos-sdk

I want to fetch blocks using golang from a blockchain which is built using cosmos-SDK.

Are there any docs which helps us to use golang client of cosmos-SDK ?

Its very annoying as i see no docs to acheive the same.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you are using **CometBFT** or **Tendermint** as the consensus mechanism for your blockchain, you may need to use different libraries for interacting with RPC. Here is the code example that you can use:

```
    package main
    
    import (
        "context"
        "github.com/cometbft/cometbft/rpc/client/http"
        "log"
    )
    
    func main() {
        rpcClient, err := http.New("https://rpc_address:443", "/websocket")
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error creating RPC client: ", err)
            return
        }
        height := int64(12345)
        resultBlock, err := rpcClient.Block(context.Background(), &height)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error receiving block: ", err)
            return
        }
        log.Println("block result: ", resultBlock)
    }
```

Set your **RPC** address with **443** port or **26657** & your block height number. Also need to note that you can use **Tendermint RPC** & **Cosmos SDK REST/LCD** for it:

**Tendermint RPC**(link depends on version & can will be changed): *https://docs.tendermint.com/v0.34/rpc/*
**Cosmos SDK REST/LCD:** *https://docs.cosmos.network/api*